Combobox does not show Persons Photos when using : Office365Users.SearchUser
I have a Combobox on powerApps, that allows searching on users. Items field is implemented like this:
AddColumns(
    Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:Combobox_1.SearchText, top:10}),
    Photo,
    Office365Users.UserPhotoV2(Mail)
)

I set also the layout as in the image

But I can not see the photos with the combobox. I tried to check this same code with a gallery component, and it works well and I can see the photos.
Why this is not working with the combobox. Is it a bug with this component or I missed some thing?
I am very new to this technology, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

combobox doesn't show images with the code that you mentioned. If the users are stored in a sharepoint list in a person type column, you will be able to connect that to a combobox and get images inside it. However, that would require you to keep updating the sharepoint list when new people join your tenant or existing people leave. To avoid all of this, if you must have the images while searching, use the gallery with a searchable textbox with dynamic height for the gallery, like when the search query in the textbox returns some data, the gallery can be made visible with appropriate height.
